# Remove lines from block title

Tags: beamer, block

Whenever I render my slides, there is always at least a vertical or horizontal (sometimes both) line in the title environment of my block sections. If it is of relevance, I am using TexStudio on Windows. Does anyone know how to remove those lines? The code to generate the below is

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\usecolortheme{beaver}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        text text text 
        
        \begin{block}{block title}
            How to remove lines in block title?
        \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: block title with lines]

Comment: That's a pdf viewer issue. It works fine with non-poppler based viewers like adobe reader